# You have four numbers, how do you figure out which one is greatest?

Tags: vb.net

Is there a very simple algorithm to figure out which of 4 numbers is the greatest?

Comment: This sounds like a problem from the 2nd homework assignment in an introductory CS class...

Comment: I agree. The general form of this question might be a bit more interesting: "For n numbers, how do you efficiently find the largest?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a language that supports some sort of max function or array sorting definitely use those features. Or choose any of the other sane answers in this thread. However, just for fun:

```
maximum = (var1 > var2 ? var1 : var2) > (var3 > var 4 ? var3 : var 4) ? 
             (var1 > var2 ? var1 : var2) : 
             (var3 > var 4 ? var3 : var 4);
```

Comment: I did this on an exam once (though it was only for three numbers).

Comment: Why dont you make it a little readable by doing this:
            `var big1 = var1 > var2 ? var1 : var2;  
            var big2 = var3 > var4 ? var3 : var4;  
            var max = big1 > big2 ? big1 : big2;  `
 Good for eye and reduces one check. But adds two assignment.

Answer (score 13):

```
  var lst = new List<int>() { 1, 7, 3, 4 };
  var max = lst.Max();
```

I got no VB, but you get the idea.

Comment: Probably wont get you an A, but that's the practical way. I think they would want you to come up with the algorithm not LINQ.

Comment: VB is almost the same: http://pastebin.com/fb2c69be

Being cautious - been a while since I've done VB. Also, remember that you need LINQ - so add your "using System.Linq", and your reference to "System.Core" (You don't need "System.Data.Linq".)

Answer (score 12):

If they are in an array, something like this should work:

VB:

```
Dim ar As Integer() = {3, 6, 9, 12}
Dim largest As Integer = ar(0)
For i As Integer = 1 To ar.Length - 1
    If ar(i) > largest Then
        largest = ar(i)
    End If
Next
```

C#:

```
int[] ar = {3, 6, 9, 12};
int largest = ar[0];
for(int i = 1; i < ar.Length; i++) {
    if(ar[i] > largest) {
        largest = ar[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is generalizable and requires only one pass over the data.

Comment: This will also work with any version of Visual Basic (even pre .NET); and the algorithm will work for any language.

Answer (score 3):

Put the numbers into an array, sort the array, then select the one whose index is array length -1.

Or you could put the numbers into an array, sort the array, reverse the array, and then select index 0.

If you need to write your own sorting algorithm, the simplest one to implement is likely to be the [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: @TheTXI Hahaha I like this answer. Bubble sort rulez cuz it has the word bubble in it! It wont get him an A but its a creative way to do it the most non-efficient way.

Comment: Bubble sort is pretty damn fast when n=4.

Comment: Insertion sort is a touch simpler to write, and usually has slightly better performance.  There is almost always no reason to write a bubble sort.

Comment: David: You'd be right. It's been so long since I wrote one that I forgot about them and now my mind is stuck thinking that bubble sort is the most basic because it's the easiest one I remember :P

Comment: Except he's not asking to SORT the array, he's asking which element is the greatest.  Bubble/insertion/any-sort is pointless in this exercise.

Comment: Actually bubblesort is somewhat well suited to this problem, as you will be guaranteed that the last element is the maximum value (assuming you are bubbling larger numbers up) after a single pass of bubblesort.  In other words, you only need to do one pass of bubblesort (O(n)) and then check the last element.

Much faster than using any other sorting algorithm, but slower than just checking each value and storing the current max.

Answer (score 3):

With VB.Net you could the following and it will work for any number of numbers

```
Public Function Max(ParamArray items As Integer()) As Integer
  if items.Length = 0 Then
    throw New ArgumentException("need at least 1 number")
  End IF
  return items.Max()
End Function
```

Then you can now do

```
Max(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways you could do this.
A really naive approach would be:

```
#Pseudocode
If number1 > number2 and number1 > number3 and number1 > number4: return number1
Else if number2 > number3 and number2 > number4: return number2
Else if number3 > number4: return number3
Else: return number4
```

It's more practical to use arrays but if you're starting that could be more complicated than simple if blocks.

Answer (score 2):

If they're in an array - and doing it explicitly rather than using sort:

```
int max = int.MinValue;   // i.e. the "largest" negative number
int largest = -1;
for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
{
    if (array[index] > max)
    {
        max = array[index];
        largest = index;
    }
}
```

The greatest value will be `max` and it's index in `largest`.

Nate's answer is more efficient as it uses the first element of the array as the initial value. So the first three lines of my solution would become:

```
int max = array[0];
int largest = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Get A, B, C, D from user;
- largest = A;
- if B > largest then
- Largest = B;
- if C > largest then
- Largest = C;
- if D > largest then
- largest = D;
- Print largest

Answer (score 0):

In Java, if a is an int[4]:

Math.max(Math.max(a[0], a[1]), Math.max(a[2], a[3]))

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim MyValues As New List(Of Double)
Dim MaxValue As Double
Dim tValue As Double

MyValues.Add(12.58)
MyValues.Add(3.58)
MyValues.Add(518.6)
MyValues.Add(244)
MyValues.Add(31.25)

For Each tValue In MyValues
    If MaxValue < tValue Then
        MaxValue = tValue

    End If
Next

MsgBox(MaxValue)
```

Answer (score -1):

My first question would be why?  Second would be, if it's only four numbers then it really doesn't matter.  Whatever takes your fancy.  I personally would go with the fewest lines of code.  Which would be to use the built in array.Sort method, then take the last item.
I would also consider using LINQ, just because you can.
Or Math.Max in a nasty nested way so Math.Max(Number1,Math.Max(Number2,Math.Max(Number3,Number4))))
If there could be hundreds of numbers, then I would try and pick a better algorithm.  Probably the one suggested by @ChrisF, although it would depend on where the numbers are coming from, EG a database could find the max much easier, or if the numbers are being read from somewhere sequentially then you could store the max as you read the numbers.

Answer (score -1):

this is my own analization. i made this code to display the lowest and highest numbers among the 4 inputted numbers from the textbox,. it will display the lowest and highest to appointed labels. if u input two same lowest or highest numbers, a msgbox appear to notify u somehow that u inputted same highest or lowest numbers and it displays back to its appropriate label. i used labels for the display of lowest and highest. here's my fb: iver saladaga anoos , 2ndyear student of JHCSC tambulig, zamboanga del sur, philippines..
so here it is! it worked for me. im using vb6 enterprise edition. :)

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim A, B, C, D As Long


A = Text1.Text
B = Text2.Text
C = Text3.Text
D = Text4.Text

If A < B And A < C And A < D Then
Label9.Caption = A
Else
If A > B And A > C And A > D Then
Label10.Caption = A
End If
```

End If

If A < B And A < D And A < C Then
   Label9.Caption = A
Else
   If A > B And A > D And A > C Then
   Label10.Caption = A
   End If
End If

If A < C And A < B And A < D Then
   Label9.Caption = A
Else
   If A > C And A > B And A > D Then
   Label10.Caption = A
   End If
   End If

If A < C And A < D And A < B Then
Label9.Caption = A
   Else
   If A > C And A > D And A > B Then
   Label10.Caption = A
   End If
End If

If A < D And A < C And A < B Then
   Label9.Caption = A
Else
   If A > D And A > C And A > B Then
   Label10.Caption = A
   End If
End If

If A < D And A < B And A < C Then
   Label9.Caption = A
Else
   If A > D And A > B And A > C Then
   Label10.Caption = A
   End If
End If

If B < C And B < A And B < D Then
   Label9.Caption = B
Else
   If B > C And B > A And B > D Then
   Label10.Caption = B
   End If
End If

If B < C And B < D And B < A Then
   Label9.Caption = B
Else
   If B > C And B > D And B > A Then
   Label10.Caption = B
   End If
End If

If B < A And B < C And B < D Then
   Label9.Caption = B
Else
   If B > A And B > C And B > D Then
   Label10.Caption = B
   End If
End If

If B < A And B < D And B < C Then
   Label9.Caption = B
Else
   If B > A And B > D And B > C Then
   Label10.Caption = B
End If
End If

If B < D And B < C And B < A Then
   Label9.Caption = B
Else
   If B > D And B > C And B > A Then
   Label10.Caption = B
   End If
End If

If B < D And B < A And B < C Then
   Label9.Caption = B
Else
   If B > D And B > A And B > C Then
   Label10.Caption = B
   End If
End If

If C < A And C < B And C < D Then
   Label9.Caption = C
Else
   If C > A And C > B And C > D Then
   Label10.Caption = C
End If
End If

If C < A And C < D And C < B Then
   Label9.Caption = C
Else
   If C > A And C > D And C > B Then
   Label10.Caption = C
   End If
End If

If C < B And C < A And C < D Then
   Label9.Caption = C
    Else
   If C > B And C > A And C > D Then
    Label10.Caption = C
    End If
End If

```
If C < B And C < D And C < A Then
Label9.Caption = C
```

Else
    If C > B And C > D And C > A Then
    Label10.Caption = C
    End If
End If

```
If C < D And C < A And C < B Then
Label9.Caption = C
Else
If C > D And C > A And C > B Then
Label10.Caption = C
End If
```

End If

```
  If C < D And C < B And C < A Then
 Label9.Caption = C
Else
If C > D And C > B And C > A Then
Label10.Caption = C
End If
```

End If

```
 If D < A And D < B And D < C Then
Label9.Caption = D
```

Else
    If D > A And D > B And D > C Then
    Label10.Caption = D
    End If
    End If

```
If D < A And D < C And D < B Then
Label9.Caption = D
```

Else
    If D > A And D > C And D > B Then
    Label10.Caption = D
End If
End If

```
If D < B And D < A And D < C Then
Label9.Caption = D
```

Else
    If D > B And D > A And D > C Then
    Label10.Caption = D
End If
End If

```
If D < B And D < C And D < A Then
Label9.Caption = D
Else
If D > B And D > C And D > A Then
Label10.Caption = D
End If
End If

If D < C And D < B And D < A Then
Label9.Caption = D
Else
If D > C And D > B And D > A Then
Label10.Caption = D
End If
End If

If D < C And D < A And D < B Then
 Label9.Caption = D
Else
If D > C And D > A And D > B Then
Label10.Caption = D
End If
End If
Command2.Enabled = True

If A = D And A > C And A > B Then
MsgBox "Same highest numbers (" + A + ") is inputted."
highest = A
Label10.Caption = highest
Else
If A = D And A < C And A < B Then
MsgBox "Same lowest numbers (" + A + ") is inputted."
lowest = A
Label9.Caption = lowest
End If
End If


If A = B And A > C And A > D Then
MsgBox "Same highest numbers (" + A + ") is inputted."
highest = A
Label10.Caption = highest
Else
If A = B And A < C And A < D Then
MsgBox "Same lowest numbers (" + A + ") is inputted."
lowest = A
Label9.Caption = lowest
End If
End If


If B = D And B > A And B > C Then
MsgBox "Same highest numbers (" + B + ") is inputted."
highest = B
Label10.Caption = highest
Else
If B = D And B < A And B < C Then
MsgBox "Same lowest numbers (" + B + ") is inputted."
lowest = B
Label9.Caption = lowest
End If
End If

If B = C And B > D And B > A Then
MsgBox "Same highest numbers (" + B + ") is inputted."
highest = B
Label10.Caption = highest
Else
If B = C And B < D And B < A Then
MsgBox "Same lowest numbers (" + B + ") is inputted."
lowest = B
Label9.Caption = lowest
End If
End If


If C = A And C > D And C > B Then
MsgBox "Same highest numbers (" + C + ") is inputted."
highest = C
Label10.Caption = highest
Else
If C = A And C < D And C < B Then
MsgBox "Same lowest numbers (" + C + ") is inputted."
lowest = C
Label9.Caption = lowest
End If
End If

If C = D And C > B And C > A Then
MsgBox "Same highest numbers (" + C + ") is inputted."
highest = C
Label10.Caption = highest
Else
If C = D And C < B And C < A Then
MsgBox "Same lowest numbers (" + C + ") is inputted."
lowest = C
Label9.Caption = lowest
End If
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
Text1.Text = Clear
Text2.Text = Clear
Text3.Text = Clear
Text4.Text = Clear
Label9.Caption = Clear
Label10.Caption = Clear
Command2.Enabled = False
Command1.Enabled = False
Text1.SetFocus

 End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
End
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Command2.Enabled = False
Command1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_Change()
Command1.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution seems overly complex and verbose.  Did you have a look at the other answers here?  They might give you an idea how this can be done with much less typing.

Comment: @tarleb he gets +1 for gangsta solution

Comment: @IIIIIllllllllIlllllIIIIIIIIlll  I guess that's fair :D

Comment: The question asked for VB.NET, not VB6 :(